# How to get low stock products list based on website in magento

Tags: magento

I have multiple website in my magento application , How can i get low stock products list based on website in magento

Comment: Go to System->Configuration->Inventory->Product Stock Options and set Notify for Quantity Below to the required value.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('is_in_stock', 0)
->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0));
```

Stock can only be controlled globally not website based

Comment: thanks Dushyant . we cannot control stock based on website ? is there any extension available for that ?